# setting up virtual machine and host OS using commandline of virtual box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I have virtualbox installed on my linux and windows I want to know how can I setup virtual machine without opening the window of virtual box from the commandline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creating a Virtual Machine using the VirtualBox command line tools:

We’re using Windows Server 2008 64bit as an example, modify to taste.

```
$ VM='Windows-2008-64bit'
```

Create a 32GB “dynamic” disk.

```
$ VBoxManage createhd --filename $VM.vdi --size 32768
```

You can get a list of the OS types VirtualBox recognises using:

```
$ VBoxManage list ostypes
```

Then copy the most appropriate one into here.

```
$ VBoxManage createvm --name $VM --ostype "Windows2008_64" --register
```

Add a SATA controller with the dynamic disk attached.

```
$ VBoxManage storagectl $VM --name "SATA Controller" --add sata \
>  --controller IntelAHCI
$ VBoxManage storageattach $VM --storagectl "SATA Controller" --port 0 \
>  --device 0 --type hdd --medium $VM.vdi
```

Add an IDE controller with a DVD drive attached, and the install ISO inserted into the drive:

```
$ VBoxManage storagectl $VM --name "IDE Controller" --add ide
$ VBoxManage storageattach $VM --storagectl "IDE Controller" --port 0 \
>  --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium /path/to/windows_server_2008.iso
```

Misc system settings.

```
$ VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --ioapic on
$ VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --boot1 dvd --boot2 disk --boot3 none --boot4 none
$ VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --memory 1024 --vram 128
$ VBoxManage modifyvm $VM --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 e1000g0
```

Configuration is all done, boot it up! If you’ve done this one a remote machine, you can RDP to the console via vboxhost:3389.

```
$ VBoxHeadless -s $VM
```

Once you have configured the operating system, you can shutdown and eject the DVD.

```
$ VBoxManage storageattach $VM --storagectl "IDE Controller" --port 0 \
>  --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium none
```

Finally, it’s a good idea to take regular snapshots so that you can always revert back to a known-good state rather than having to completely re-install.

```
$ VBoxManage snapshot $VM take <name of snapshot>
```

And, if you need to revert back to a particular snapshot:

```
$ VBoxManage snapshot $VM restore <name of snapshot>
```

Hope that helps..